# WPF Cursor Blink rate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have noticed that the cursor blinks really slowly in my WPF apps. This is much much slower then in the rest of windows. I'm seeing it working at about half the rate.

If I adjust the blink rate in the control panel it does speed up the WPF blink rate, but only proportionally, it is still twice as slow as what is shown in the control panel and what is used in the rest of windows.

What I would like is for the Cursor blink rate to match the standard windows cursor blink rate.

If this is not possible I would at least like to know why there is such a huge difference.

Comment: ....? The control panel setting seems to affect WPF on my comp...?

Comment: increasing the control panel blink rate does increase the WPF blink rate but it is still twice as slow as what is shown in the control panel and what is used in the rest of windows.